# .htaccess RewriteRule: перенаправить ссылки

Tags: apache, .htaccess, php, регулярные-выражения

Здравствуйте знатоки.

Необходимо перенаправить все ссылки начинающиеся с "/u/" на regestration.php?ref=$1,
при этом все ссылки кроме первого условия на "/u/" на system/pages.php?page=$1

Таким образом не выходит:

```
RewriteRule ([^u])|(.*)$ system/pages.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^u/([A-Za-z]*)$  regestration.php?&ref=$1 [L]
```

pages - domen.name/main.html ... domen.name/index.html ... т.е. domen.name/[AZ-az].html
regestration - domen.name/u/userone ... т.е. domen.name/u/[AZ-az]

Необходима Ваша помощь.

Comment: Нвучитесь внятно трактовать вопросы, лично я ничего не понял! Ищите информацию в ПС по запросу `RedirectMatch 301`составляйте выражение и получите необходимый результат.

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ system/pages.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^u/([^/]*)$ regestration.php?ref=$1 [L]
```

index.* скорее всего, в силу приоритетов, под это условие не попадет.

Answer (score 0):

[A-Za-z] - это только буквы. В URL других символов нет? Приведите пример ссылки, которая будет обрабатываться regestration.php.

Когда разберетесь с этим правилом, все остальное можно будет отправлять на system/pages.php.

Comment: Сергей других символов в url нет.<br><br>pages - domen.name/main.html<br>reg  - domen.name/u/username

Comment: Попробуйте с первым правилом так:

RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z]*)\.html$ system/pages.php?page=$1 [nc]

Answer (score 0):

```
http://site/u/avtor
http://site/u/napoleon
```

<p>на regestration.php?&amp;ref=$1</p>

```
http://site/
http://site/about.html
http://site/tarif.html
```

<p>на system/pages.php?page=$1</p>